# How to solve User profile request failed in Google social login

Tags: php, google-authentication, google-signin, hybrid

When I try to login with google authentication, gives me an error. I have use Hybrid authentication use. It's work on `HTTP` but not working on `HTTPS`.
Please see the error:

> User profile request failed. Most likely the user is not connected to
>   the provider and he should authenticate again. Ooophs, we got an
>   error: User profile request failed! Google returned an error:
>   exception 'Exception' with message 'The Authorization Service has
>   return

**Code**

```
$hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $setting ); 
$provider = $hybridauth->authenticate( $this->session->data['provider']); 
//get the user profile 
$profile = $provider->getUserProfile(); 
$this->register($this->session->data['provider'], (array)$profile);
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue with HybridAuth

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth2Client class has recently been changed in order to be compliant with the RFC6749 specifications.
Check them out here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1

I believe this only affected POST requests.

Get the update in this PR: https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/pull/707

I believe this has been merged into the master now as well, so you could just grab a new copy of the code and update locally.